# Tell me which version sdk download in android

Tags: android, device

I have an doubt with Sdk in android.Let me explain in which vision I need to download to develop the app for v4&5

Comment: v4 & v5 of what? if you mean the android api level, why are you developing for android 1.6 & 2.0?

Comment: I think he means 4.0 and 5.0.  At least for his sanity I hope so.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop apps for Android Version 4.0 and 5.0, you need to download at least the Android API 14 (for 4.0, which is KitKat) and the Android API 21 (for 5.0, which is Android Lollipop.